Making 3d pixel art water in blender with correct reflection in EEVEE
I am trying to make a 3D-pixel art scene that requires an ocean with reflections. I am using Lucas Roedel's pixel art addon. (https://lucasroedel.gumroad.com/l/pixel_art). His library essentially does the dithering for you and the cell shading all in EEVEE. However, I tried hard but the reflection did not appear. For example, I would add a cube to the scene and make it sit right on top of the water shader, but nothing happened. I know you can get reflections with baking cube maps but that also doesn't work and I don't understand why. Can anyone please help me? Thanks!

I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking for, is it a problem to get reflections with this addon or to get any reflections in general using EEVEE? If the latter, have you enabled Screen Space Reflections in the Render Properties?

Thanks for replying. I was just wondering if it is possible to get a reflective surface like water with pixel art dithering. I have enabled screen space reflections and I have tried baking the reflection with the cube map, but nothing works.
